# Mongodb query: generate "table format" in result query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with the network traffic amount per IP & MAC, in a amount of days. The collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "ip" : "190.112.100.0",
        "date" : "05/10/2020",
        "mac" : "bcd1657bca6e"
    },
    "total_in_bytes" : 237203,
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "ip" : "191.110.90.0",
        "date" : "05/10/2020",
        "mac" : "bcd165bc8ae5"
    },
    "total_in_bytes" : 197102,
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "ip" : "190.112.100.0",
        "date" : "06/10/2020",
        "mac" : "bcd1657bca6e"
    },
    "total_in_bytes" : 205210,
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "ip" : "190.112.100.0",
        "date" : "07/10/2020",
        "mac" : "bcd1657bca6e"
    },
    "total_in_bytes" : 223245,
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "ip" : "191.110.90.0",
        "date" : "07/10/2020",
        "mac" : "bcd165bc8ae5"
    },
    "total_in_bytes" : 208200,
}
```

Now I need to get the number of "total_in_bytes" per day, in table format or equivalent CSV

```
ip              |   mac         |   05/10/2020      |   06/10/2020      |   07/10/2020
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
190.112.100.0       bcd1657bca6e    237203              205210              223245
191.110.90.0        bcd165bc8ae5    197102              -----               208200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some JavaScript. Something like this (not tested):

```
var header = ["ip", "mac"];
var dates = db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: null, date_set: {$addToSet: "$_id.date"}}}
]).toArray().shift().date_set;
header.push(dates);

print(header.join("|"));

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { ip: "$_id.ip", mac: "$_id.mac" },
      data: {
        $push: {
          total_in_bytes: "$total_in_bytes",
          date: "$_id.date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
   var row = [doc._id.ip, doc._id.mac];
   dates.forEach(function(d) {
      doc.data.forEach(function(val) {
        if (val.date == d) 
          row.push(val.total_in_bytes);
      });
   });
   print(row .join("|"));
})
```

Comment: Thanks Wernfried Domscheit. This work partially, because if an IP address not contain network traffic in a particular date, not print a blank space or some caracter that indicates the vacant data.

Comment: Yes, I know but I think you got an idea how the code could look like.